# Authorization Bearer token HEADER is not been added to ApiClient in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I was developing an app where I need to pass a sessionToken recover on a register screen to the rest of app call's.

The register call goes fine and bring me the token correctly, but when I try to add it to my ApiClient, is look like it isn't.

I add my Log:

```
token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJUQ09EIjoiVk5HVTciLCJtYWNBZGRyZXNzIjoiQzg6NDA6NTI6MUE6NkI6NkEiLCJzZXJpYWwiOiIwMTg1MTU0NDM0NyIsImNvbXBhbnl

<-- 500 https://647od1l7ug.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api/terminals/shiftOpen (636ms)
2023-09-22 12:35:02.956  8793-8878  okhttp.OkHttpClient     es.paytef.cepsastandalone            I  date: Fri, 22 Sep 2023 10:35:02 GMT
2023-09-22 12:35:02.957  8793-8878  okhttp.OkHttpClient     es.paytef.cepsastandalone            I  content-type: application/json
2023-09-22 12:35:02.958  8793-8878  okhttp.OkHttpClient     es.paytef.cepsastandalone            I  content-length: 35
2023-09-22 12:35:02.959  8793-8878  okhttp.OkHttpClient     es.paytef.cepsastandalone            I  apigw-requestid: Lp4ZngPvjoEEMwQ=
2023-09-22 12:35:02.963  8793-8878  okhttp.OkHttpClient     es.paytef.cepsastandalone            I  {"message":"Internal Server Error"}
2023-09-22 12:35:02.964  8793-8878  okhttp.OkHttpClient     es.paytef.cepsastandalone            I  <-- END HTTP (35-byte body)
```

THe firts line of the call is return when I build my Client on this class:

```
  fun provideCepsaApi(token: String): CepsaApi {
        val resp = ApiClient(
            baseUrl = BuildConfig.BASE_URL,
            converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(),
            okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient
        )
        if (token.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.d("http es.paytef", "token: $token")
            resp.addAuthorization("Authorization Bearer") { chain ->
                val originalRequest = chain.request()
                val originalHttpUrl = originalRequest.url

                val url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder().build()
                val requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                    .url(url)

                val request = requestBuilder.build()
                chain.proceed(request)
            }
        }
        return resp.createService(CepsaApi::class.java)
    }
```

Regarding how manage my useCase:

```
@ActivityRetainedScoped
class ShiftOpenUseCase @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context,
) {

    suspend fun shiftOpen(token: String, time: String): WrapperResponse<ShiftOpenResponse> {
        val cepsaApi = NetworkModule().provideCepsaApi(token)
        val response = try {
            cepsaApi.shiftOpen(
                shiftOpenRequest = ShiftOpenRequest(startTime = time)
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return WrapperResponse.Error(context.getString(R.string.errorService, "shiftOpen: ${e.message}"))
        }
        return WrapperResponse.Success(response)
    }
}
```

As you can check there some value added on the header as content-type, or content-lenght, which are been added by a middleware layer, but my header is been ignored.

So what Am I missing? Should I change the way a create my client adding header otherway?

Take thanks in advance!

Comment: you are passing token to  "provideCepsaApi"  function which is not updated next API call as you are using DI. You need to pass token in API interface class as a parameter.